# Nested Loop functions Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

Given num_rows and num_cols, output the label for each seat of a theater. Each seat is followed by a space, and each row is followed by a newline. Define the outer for loop, initialize curr_col_let with the starting row letter, and define the inner for loop.

I have seen this question asked before, but I did not see a usable solution for what I have to work with.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
num_rows = int(input()) #line locked and can not be altered.
num_cols = int(input()) #line locked and can not be altered.

curr_row = 1
curr_col_let = 'A'
for row in range(num_rows):
  for col in range(num_cols):
      print (f'{curr_row}{curr_col_let}', end=' ')  #line locked and can not be altered.
      curr_col_let = chr(ord(curr_col_let) + 1)  #line locked and can not be altered.
  print() #line locked and can not be altered.
```

Current Output:
[current output and expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wuy1.png)

I wanted to add the row + 1 after the print on line 8, but Zylab will not let me alter lines 1, 2, 8, 9, 10.  I can enter new lines between line 2 and the first print function.  Struggling to figure out what function can be put in above the print function to increase the row after the column iterations.

Comment: You can't change the print statement, but you can change the variables that it is printing. For example, using `for curr_row in range(1, num_rows+1):` as your outer loop will give you the counts you want. Then moving `curr_col_let = 'A'` inside outer loop will reset it for every row.

Comment: Awesome.  I knew it was something small I was missing.  I really appreciate it.  Was racking my brain for 2 hours.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `curr_row = 1` and change the outermost for-loop with `curr_row` variable (and adjust the `range()` accordingly).

Also reset the `curr_col_let` to `A` every new row.

```
num_rows = int(input())  # line locked and can not be altered.
num_cols = int(input())  # line locked and can not be altered.

for curr_row in range(1, num_rows + 1):
    curr_col_let = "A"
    for _ in range(num_cols):
        print(f"{curr_row}{curr_col_let}", end=" ")
        curr_col_let = chr(ord(curr_col_let) + 1)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
2
3
1A 1B 1C 
2A 2B 2C
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.  I see I had my range set incorrectly.  Appreciate it very much.